# What is the command for importing a sql file and its schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, sqlite, dump

I have an empty sqlite3 db. I would like to import a pre-existing one with all of its schema and data. What is the proper code command for that?

I tried :

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 < new-sql.sql
```

It flashes by all the data, and a bunch of junk, and the CPU beeps a few times, and nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those interested:

```
sqlite3 new-sql.sql .dump | sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
```

Comment: Be sure and accept your own answer when the two days have passed.